# Access Denied to different server on Virtual Directory in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I setup an asp.net web application on IIS that I have setup several times for other clients but getting a strange permission issue on this one.

It's setup so the App Pool Identity is NetworkService and the folder being used has Network Service as a permitted user with full permissions.  The folder can be browsed from the server the application is on and items added, edited and deleted.

But for a reason I cannot determine any time the application tries to access a file from the virtual directory I get 'Access is Denied'.  I have checked permissions on the root folder of the actual application which also has Network Service and checked the virtual directory permissions use the identity as well, not sure what else to try?

Comment: Is the site set to use the application pool's identity under Anonymous Authentication?

Comment: Yep as far as permissions go in IIS there is no problem that I can see.  If I change the virtual directory to a folder on the same server there is no issue, its only when selecting the folder on another server.